# Using single certificate for all users

Tags: android, certificate

I'm thinking about using a CA for authenticating over https with my app to my web server.

My question is: How easy would it be for a hacker to steal that cert from the phone?

The scenario is: every user of my app uses the same cert which comes bundled with the app, someone digs it out of the phone (somehow?), posts it on the web and now the web server is getting ddos'd.  I then have to invalidate the cert, but then I've invalidated **all** my users.

How difficult is it going to be for a hacker to do this?  If it's easy, then it may not be worth having a cert at all.

Comment: I wouldn't even call that hacking...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say trivial to extract it from the app. There are two parts: certificate (which is essentially the public key), and secret key.

For HTTPS, the certificate is presented in clear on the wire, and is used to establish the encrypted session.

But it's not the certificate you worry about - that is public, and needs to be - it's the other half, the secret key. For HTTPS to work you need to perform part of the initial establishment sequence with the secret key.

A crucial part of the certificate and secret key is the same. A set of bytes known as the Modulus. Take that from the wire (as it will be there), search your app image for the same modulus and your hacker will have the secret part nearby, and can spoof away to his heart's content.

Bad idea, really.